# ExceptionFilterAttribute.OnException not called, when exception thrown from a service

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Having trouble in understanding when does ExceptionFilterAttribute invokes OnException method.

Lets say I have 2 registered filters:

```
filters.Add<ExceptionFilter>();
filters.Add<ActionExecutionFilter>();
```

Where ExceptionFilter overrides OnException and ActionExecutionFilter has OnActionExecution and for test purposes it has OnResultExecuted.

What I found out is - if I throw exception straight into the action, it calls OnException method, 
but If I throw exception in any of my dependency injected services (see in examples), then it doesn't invoke the OnException method. When the exception happens in any of those cases (second example), then I know that ActionFilter will invoke OnResultExecuted method, where I can see the exception, which goes straight to middleware exception handler.

What I want to know is why doesn't ExceptionFilter invoke any method if Result has exception in it.

Examples:

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod()
{
    throw new Exception("this one calls OnException");
    //Logic
}

public ActionResult SomeActionMethod()
{
    var result = this._injectedService.ThrowExceptionMethod(); // --> This one doesn't call OnException if it appears
    //Logic
}
```

Comment: That's odd. Mind to paste content of the exception filter? Also, is `ThrowExceptionMethod` an async method (returning `Task` or `Task<T>`)? If yes, do you await it? If not, the exceptions of async method won't be catched unless a) `await`ed  or b) `task.Result` (blocking, bad, throws AggregateException rather than the specific one) or c) `task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is called

Comment: Thanks for the comment, much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this puzzle. The problem wasn't in .net core or exception attribute at all. I am using interceptors for dataManagers & dataAccess instances and therefore after I throw exception in one of those instances the interceptor wraps that error and returns it as normal result, which causes OnResultExecuted invoke with exception in it.